# How to change the color of Html.DisplayFor boolean result

Tags: c#, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

The rendered result for Html.DisplayFor on a boolean value is a disabled checkbox. I just want to change its color. I've looked on many websites, including this one, but most of the help around this topic is for people who want to change the display to between two text values.

I created a custom css file and referenced it in my layout page, but it does not do anything.

```
input[type="checkbox"].disabled {
   color: #ccc
}
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ASI Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles/custom.css"/>
    @RenderSection("Style",false) 
</head>
```

Declared the section in my razor page.

```
@section style{
}
```

I can see in the chrome inspector that the HTML is written such that 
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.xx.yy)` returns `<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox"/>` on my page. The types match, so why does the color still not change? I know I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After looking at the element itself, all of the "color" elements are striked through, and I can see my custom style. It would seem it has no other color references to go by except mine, yet the checkbox is still the dull grey instead of changing colors.

```
element.style {
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    color: #e83e8c;
    background-color: #6f42c1;
    border-color: #ff6a00;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
button, input {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i]:disabled {
    <strike>background-color: initial;</strike>
}
user agent stylesheet
input:disabled {
    <strike>background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.3));
    border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.3);</strike>
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input:disabled {
    <strike>color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(84, 84, 84), rgb(170, 170, 170));</strike>
    cursor: default;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    <strike>background-color: initial;</strike>
    cursor: default;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    <strike>color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white);</strike>
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    <strike>background-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    <strike>border-color: -internal-light-dark-color(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(195, 195, 195));</strike>
    border-image: initial;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

EDIT: I have included a screenshot of the inspector. The attributes are seen correctly, but they do not apply.
[Screenshot of inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i23eB.png)

Comment: Did you try using ```input[type="checkbox"]:disabled```?

Comment: @AnishKumar I had a period instead of a colon, so I fixed that. But it still does not change colors even though I can see it in the inspector and there are no other apparent color references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use disabled as a class of the input type checkbox. So `input[type="checkbox"].disabled` works when you have HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box disabled" />
```

But that is not the case here. Your HTML is coming like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" />
```

You are getting an attribute added (which is the default behaviour of the HTML disabling). Hence what you need to change your CSS style is to use either one of the below:

```
input[type="checkbox"][disabled] {
    // customize here
}
```

OR

```
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
    // customize here
}
```

**NOTE:** I have never checked the 2nd one myself but have tried the 1st one. It works!

Comment: I also want to ask you if you need to handle the styling of the text of the checkbox disabled as well? Because this will not change anything for the text as the input tag only takes care of the box.

Comment: Thank you for answering, however it appears that still nothing has changed. See my latest edit, I have included a photo. I have tried both methods you mentioned, and the attributes are there, but the box is still grey.

Comment: Can I help you on jsfiddle? Add your piece of HTML code and the css used on jsfiddle and post the ling here. I think there is something missing.

Comment: It may be slightly different because I am writing this in C#, then it is translated to HTML. However, here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tak4zymL/

Comment: oh.. so you are just using the default checkbox. If you use a default checkbox, it will be controlled by the browser and you cannot change the style for it. You need to add customisation to the checkbox.
You can check the following links for customisation:
https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-mvc-ui-controls/checkbox
http://jsfiddle.net/f9tLemyy/

Comment: It seems to me that the first link needs a subscription to something, and the jsfiddle is more or less what I'm trying to do. However, it is just hiding the checkbox and creating another one with a string. I need to change the color of the checkbox fill.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of it all, it turns out this was just me not understanding how to manually input the HTML instead of relying on @Html.DisplayFor.

Forcing the HTML as 
`<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" checked="@Model.Class.Item" disabled />`

I left this link in the head section of my layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then, I used the google chrome inspector to find the right css elements.

```
<style>
    .custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label::before {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:disabled:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
        border-color: grey;
    }
    .custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='green' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
</style>
```